# How can I get the context of the activity which is calling a static function?

Tags: android, android-activity, static, android-context

I have a network class making use of the following lib: [Lib Docs](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html) with 4 function to make a get, post delete and put request to the server. here is the simplified version:

```
 public static void get(Context context, String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {          
    httpClient.get(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}
```

Now instead of having to pass the context through via a paramter, Is there no possible way to some how get the context of the calling activity inside the fucntion?

some thing along the lines of:

```
public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    Context context = getCallignActivtyCntext() // <====== some thing like this
    httpClient.get(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}
```

the reason I need the specific context is because I have to cancel all network requests when an activity is destroyed, and it groups or identifies all requests by the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually need the specific context of the caller for your methods, you can just use the Application context through `getApplicationContext()`

To statically access your Application context you can do something like this:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        this.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then in your manifest you declare your application name to match your custom class

```
<application android:name="com.path.to.class.CustomApplication" ...>
```

Comment: But now will this be able to identify each activities context? Because the reason I am needing this context is in orde rto call the cancelRequests see: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html#cancelRequests(android.content.Context, boolean)

Comment: Ahh I see. Unfortunately the only way have cancelRequests work correctly is if you pass in the callers context to make the request and to cancel it.

Comment: Thx. Im gona have to do that then. And can i get teh specific context of an activity by the following:  `ActivityName.this`

Comment: You can as long as you call it within a non-static function in your Activity class

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, no context would exist within a static method. The only way would be to pass a parameter in. You could get this from an intent, but not a standard static method call. There might be a solution but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

While this is possible by inspecting the stack trace, this would certainly be more complicating than just passing the context.

There is no simpler solution. Moreover, getting the caller of a method is not recommended for security reasons.